# Finding the coordinates on an edge of a square

Tags: javascript, performance, computational-geometry

I wrote a calculation that finds coordinates on an edge of a square, but it came out as a really long nested tangle of conditions. After some reduction and finding common pieces I arrived at this example:

```
  // targetX, targetY, sourceX, sourceY are provided as parameters
  // and are markers for the centers of the two locations connecting
  let tx;
  let ty;
  const dx = targetX - sourceX;
  const dy = targetY - sourceY;
  const adjY = (radius * Math.tan(Math.atan2(dy, dx)));
  const adjX = (radius / Math.tan(Math.atan2(dy, dx)));
  if (Math.abs(adjY) <= radius) { // A
    if (targetX <= sourceX) { // B
      tx2 = targetX + (Math.abs(adjX) <= radius ? adjX : radius);
      ty2 = targetY + (Math.abs(adjY) <= radius ? adjY : radius);
    } else {
      tx2 = targetX - (Math.abs(adjX) <= radius ? adjX : radius);
      ty2 = targetY - (Math.abs(adjY) <= radius ? adjY : radius);
    }
  } else if (targetY <= sourceY) { // C
    tx2 = targetX + (Math.abs(adjX) <= radius ? adjX : radius);
    ty2 = targetY + (Math.abs(adjY) <= radius ? adjY : radius);
  } else {
    tx2 = targetX - (Math.abs(adjX) <= radius ? adjX : radius);
    ty2 = targetY - (Math.abs(adjY) <= radius ? adjY : radius);
  }
```

Moving several of the conditions into the lines themselves was possible using ternary operators. But now I'm stuck, so how do I reduce the conditions even further?

I thought of using boolean logic gate reduction techniques, like Karnaugh maps, but fail to find a way to map that process to my problem.

Other solutions involving different math are welcome as well.

The problem is finding the new target X and Y so that they meet the edge of the target rectangle instead of its center.

[image: diagram-of-the-problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is a little simplier

```
const dx = targetX - sourceX;
const dy = targetY - sourceY;
const scale = Math.hypot(dx, dy) / Math.hypot(radius,radius * (Math.abs(dy / dx) < 1 ? dy / dx : dx / dy));
const tx = targetX - dx / scale;
const ty = targetY - dy / scale;
```

If it is just the boundary of the box you are after. The only comparison is to find out which part of the box the line ends on, top/bottom or left/right the rest works by preserving dx and dy's sign. It also works if `dx` or `dy` is zero.

The only thing I am not sure of is if the offset is from the target, if so I would change to

```
const dx = sourceX - targetX;
const dy = sourceY - targetY;
const scale = Math.hypot(dx, dy) / Math.hypot(radius,radius * (Math.abs(dy / dx) < 1 ? dy / dx : dx / dy));
const tx = targetX + dx / scale;
const ty = targetY + dy / scale;
```

Comment: The first option (with the subtraction) works flawlessly! Thank you very much. A much more elegant solution than my own.

Comment: Went into working code at https://github.com/kesor/vue-ccpm/commit/a3f6b87b

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to extract some values into variables.

First of all, you are always using `Math.abs(adjX) <= radius ? adjX : radius` for both X and Y so those can be extracted into `changeX` or `changeY`.

Next, you are either doing `+` or `-` which can be changed into using a `multiplier` that is either \$1\$ or \$-1\$.

And as a last step, the `multiplier` can be set using the conditional ternary operator.

Then what you end up with is this:

```
let tx;
let ty;
const dx = targetX - sourceX;
const dy = targetY - sourceY;
const adjY = (radius * Math.tan(Math.atan2(dy, dx)));
const adjX = (radius / Math.tan(Math.atan2(dy, dx)));

const changeX = Math.abs(adjX) <= radius ? adjX : radius;
const changeY = Math.abs(adjY) <= radius ? adjY : radius;
let multiplier;
if (Math.abs(adjY) <= radius) {
  multiplier = targetX <= sourceX ? 1 : -1;
} else {
  multiplier = targetY <= sourceY ? 1 : -1;
}
tx2 = targetX + multiplier * changeX;
ty2 = targetY + multiplier * changeY;
```

Comment: Need to change last lines to not mix arithmetic operators. Placing bracers around the multiplication.

Comment: @Evgeny Multiplication takes precedence before addition, so no braces needed.

Comment: Yes it works. But a good practice, to avoid human error when changing code later, is not to mix arithmetic operators.

Comment: @Evgeny That's your preference, personally I don't worry about mixing addition and multiplication like that. If it makes you feel any better, you could do `multiplier * changeX + targetX`